# How to detect if antivirus/firewall is blocking my application?

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi, firewall, antivirus

I have a downloader which work fine, but sometimes the user's antivirus/firewall blocks its file write access and/or downloading. Is there a way to detect that?

Comment: Those overzealous antivirus/firewall programs are always fun...

Comment: you should get an "access denied" error code when either trying to exec or to read the just downloaded file. Usually AV does not block the writing but will delete it on next read.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using C# use a try/catch block and catch the [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx).
That's the cleanest and most standard way of handling it.

Note: this won't tell you if the AV caught it, and neither should you check: that's the problem of the user and their AV.
If your program was denied access to some of the user's resource and you believe you had a legitimate reason to access that resource, inform the user with a nice text boxt and let them sort it out with their AV. You can for example suggest that your downloader be in the AV's trusted program list.

Comment: That's what I do, but what should I do about firewalls? Sometimes it just gives me Timed out, so I guess the firewalls do more than just port blocking.

Comment: There is no standard. You have no way to differentiate between the firewall blocking the packets causing it to timeout or the remote server not being contactable causing it to timeout. This would be the same for an external firewall. Just handle the error and report what the error says to the user.